# Silverlight - Possible to not rotate parent window overlay when ChildWindow rotates?

Tags: silverlight, rotation, childwindow

I've got a ChildWindow that rotates 180 degrees when I click a button.
I'm also using a ChildWindow.OverlayBrush to dim out the parent window.
This of course rotates as well when the ChildWindow rotates.
Is there anyway to dim out the parent window without it rotating with the ChildWindow?

Answer (score 0):

2 options spring to mind:

1. You either need the OverlayBrush to
   not be under the same element you
   rotate (can you rotate a child
   within the window instead?)
2. Or, you need to rotate the overlay
   brush in the opposite direct in the
   same animation so that it cancels
   out the motion.